VS Code + httpyac not finding variables?
Here is the test.html file:
@authtoken = 3013faa12e899d827e59aae6b7fc67be00f768ee

###
GET http://localhost:8000/api/warehausedefs/
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Token {{authtoken}}

> {%
   const responseData = response.body;
   warehouseId = responseData.results[0].id;
%}

### 
GET http://localhost:8000/api/warehausedefs/{{warehouseId}}/
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Token {{authtoken}}

This works when I send request 1 followed by request 2. But for some reason VSCode says there is a problem:
[{
    "resource": "/<...>/test/test.http",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "warehouseId is not found",
    "startLineNumber": 14,
    "startColumn": 45,
    "endLineNumber": 14,
    "endColumn": 60
}]


How do I satisfy VSCode to remove the Problem?
The script(s) work but VSCode decides there is a problem.
